# Manually setting the SCAN_WIDTH and SCAN_HEIGHT causes ZXing to crash

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I'm using the popular [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) project to enable barcode scanning on my Android application.

I want to manually set the width and height of my viewfinder, so I used the following:

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 400);
intent.putExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 300);
```

Before sending my intent. However, the app crashes due to a `NullPointerException` at line 279 in `CameraManager.java`. I did some debugging and it looks like the `screenResolution` member of `configManager` is never initialized. I debugged some more, to find that `surfaceCreated()` is not called in time (this is supposed to be done through a Callback). At least, that is what it seems like to me, since `surfaceCreated()` in `CaptureActivity.java` is responsible for initializing those members of `configManager`. I did some searching on here and Google but it doesn't seem like people use those intent extras `SCAN_WIDTH` and `SCAN_HEIGHT`. They are manually setting the `MIN` and `MAX` width/height values within the ZXing code, which I am trying to avoid. Any help would be appreciated.

The scanner works fine when I am not setting those width/height values via intent.

**EDIT:** After updating my version of the ZXing library, this is no longer an issue. It also fixed the front camera issue I was having with the 2012 Nexus 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`screenResolution` is definitely set, in `initFromCameraParameters`. It happens when the driver opens. It's OK if `surfaceCreated` happens a bit later since the `onResume` method registers a callback to initialize the camera after the surface is created, if it's not already available.

`onResume` calls `setManualFramingRect` even if it's not initialized, but, in that case it just saves the request in `requestedFramingRectWidth` and `requestedFramingRectHeight` and sets it later.

I think this case is handled correctly, but as ever I can't be 100% sure there's not an oversight. Maybe you can say more about where you think the problem is given this info.

Comment: After some careful review, I realized that my version of ZXing is pretty much ancient, as I don't even have the `requested` members that store the dimensions for later. I will let you know if my issue is resolve once I've upgraded it. Looks like the `setManualFramingRect` method handles cases where the camera is not yet initialized so I think it will work.